# Reposition mouse to window in focus? (ie. after cmd + tab)

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, mouse, keyboard-navigation

I've got 2 external monitors connected my Macbook Pro Retina, totalling 3 screens. I often switch between windows and need the mouse to click something. I'd love a way to say

> center the mouse pointer on this window (in focus)

I don't see neither Witch, WindowFlow, BetterSnapshotTool or any other from my google-ing that does this. Hopefully I missed something. Thanks!

Comment: I know logitech has this on Windows. Called 'Smart Move' if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I found this free app, [Catchmouse](http://ftnew.com/catchmouse.html), that allow me to create shortcuts I hit to center the mouse on a screen. Three shortcuts for my three screens. It certainly helps although not as smart as the "center on window in focus". Build that and I'll pay a few bucks for it. Ideas for free :)